# Validar dentro de un modal con JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

estoy trabajando en un proyecto y me he topado con este problema, el problema es cuando le doy grabar al momento que voy a registrar una marca de un producto en un modal, el modal se cierra y me sale un mensaje de validación (Ingrese la marca), cómo podría hacer que cuando salga un mensaje de validación o error el modal se mantenga abierto pero cuando este ok el modal se cierre.

Codigo xhtml del modal:

```
<!-- Dialog para registrar marca -->
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
            <h:form id="frmRegistro">
                <div class="bootbox modal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <!-- Modal header -->
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="pci-cross pci-circle"></i></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Nueva Marca</h4>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /Modal header -->
                            <!-- Modal body -->
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Ingrese los datos requeridos para crear una nueva marca.</p>
                                <hr/>
                                <div class="bootbox-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3"><span class="form_required">*</span> Nombre:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtMarca" 
                                                                     value="#{marcaController.marca.c_t_marca}"
                                                                     styleClass="form-control" 
                                                                     required="true"
                                                                     requiredMessage="Ingrese la marca"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Abrev:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtMarcaAbre" 
                                                                     value="#{marcaController.marca.c_t_marca_abre}"
                                                                     styleClass="form-control"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-5"><span class="form_required">*</span>
                                                        <small>Contenido Obligatorio</small>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /Modal body -->
                            <!-- Modal footer -->
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <h:commandButton value="Grabar"
                                                 action="#{marcaController.RegistrarMarca(marcaController.marca)}"
                                                 onclick="javascript:if(!confirm('¿Desea registrar marca?')) return false;"
                                                 styleClass="btn btn-purple"
                                                 style="font-size:12px;"/>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /Modal footer -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Lograste ya resolver el problema?

Comment: @RaulCacacho no aun no

Comment: Lo que te falta ahi es que actualice solo cierta parte del xhtml  <h:form id="frmRegistro"> tienes esto formulario entonces el boton guardar pon update="frmRegistro" debera solo actualizar esta parte